# Server side rendering with loadable components not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, loadable-component

I have been trying for a while now, to no avail, to get my configuration working for an app that has the following characterstics:

1. Typescript
2. React
3. Server side rendering using loadable-components
4. Webpack

For some reason, this snippet, which is supposed to find all the chunks that were used during the server side rendering, is not working:

```
server.get("*", (req, res, next) => {
    const extractor = new ChunkExtractor({ statsFile });
    ...
    const tsx = extractor.collectChunks(
        <ChunkExtractorManager extractor={extractor}>
            <StaticRouter location={req.url}>
                <App data={data}/>
            </StaticRouter>
        </ChunkExtractorManager>
    );
    console.log(extractor.getScriptTags()); // prints server.js bundle but this isn't correct
});
```

It's returning the `server.js` bundle instead of the needed client/vendor bundles. Rather than post all the code here, I've pushed all the code to my branch on github: https://github.com/markdstevens/ssr-ts-react-webpack-boilerplate/tree/ssr-with-code-splitting

I must be missing some configuration in webpack or in loadable-components, but I've looked everywhere and can't seem to find the issue. Any tips would be most welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. In my webpack configuration, I had this in my server config:

```
import * as LoadablePlugin from '@loadable/webpack-plugin';
...
{
  entry: './src/server/app.tsx',
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  output: {
    filename: 'server.js',
  },
  plugins: [
    new LoadablePlugin()
  ]
}
```

I had to add the `LoadablePlugin` to my client configuration as well in order for everything to work.

Comment: Iv'e done over 800+ hrs of configuring SSR for our team, code splitting, routing, rendering react-dom portals in the header of the page on the server, client- side only components, redux hydration on server etc etc etc etc, My advice to people now on SSR with react is to use NextJS and avoid countless hours of headaches.

Comment: i get performance score around 70-80 with react and ssr in desktop. my problem is that i can't use renderToNodeStream and when i use loadable components i get a blink . here is [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66050007/react-ssr-blinks-when-starting-client) .please let me know if i can help or if you've got a clue about the problems. i really need some clues.